# How to point a domain to Aws S3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have my domain registered and hosted at Hostpapa.

I have my web hosting in AWS S3. All set up as below:

Created a bucket in AWS S3 (named myDomain.org for example) with all the website content uploaded.
I'm able to access with URL like

http://myDOmain.org.s3-website.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com

The question is how do I point the domain in Hostpapa to AWS S3 website?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out straight forward.

In AWS S3

1. Create 2 buckets

- myDomain.org
- [www.myDomain.org](http://www.myDomain.org)

2. Enable static web hosting in www bucket
3. Configure redirect for myDomain.org bucket to www
4. Upload website to www bucket
5. Copy www url (also called CNAME) like [www.myDomain.org.s3-website.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com](http://www.myDomain.org.s3-website.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com)

In Hostpapa (or whatever the domain register)
Configure sub domain www to the above url (CNAME)

Wait couple of hours for propagation.

Works prefect!!!

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to point out is that if you're trying to create a record for a root (or apex record) e.g. `example.com` you will need to ensure your domain service supports either `ANAME` or `Alias` records as traditionally only an `A` record (or `AAAA` for IPv6) will be supported for this record.

If your host supports one of these types (or is a subdomain e.g. `subdomain.example.com` in which case you can also use a `CNAME` record) you create the record and then use the CNAME provided as the value for your record.

If you are not able to configure in your current DNS provider, [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) does support Alias records so would be possible to add this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Want to clarify CNAME

Comment: Hi which additional info do you want? :)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I got it working. You're right. I should use sub domain www with CNAME.